# Dudas con curl en php

Tags: php, curl

Me estoy conectado a una API para sacar información de unos productos.

en la aplicación son mas de 100 productos, pero al momento de recorrer el array que este este me arroja, no me trae completa la información.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url_API);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
echo "➜ Obteniendo datos origen ... \n";
$items_origin = curl_exec($ch);

$items_origin = json_decode($items_origin, true);
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa *"... pero al momento de recorrer el array que este este me arroja, no me trae completa la información."*? Generalmente las APIs te devuelven los datos paginados cuando pides muchos datos. Quizá debas verificar en la doc de la API si tiene límites en ese sentido y cómo consultar datos masivos . Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta.

Comment: No me la trae completa. ya valide y tienen un limite de 30. Es posible se pueda consultar por lotes o paginación?

Comment: ¿La API no explica en su documentación cómo hacer para obtener resultados paginados? Generalmente ellos explican el mejor modo de hacerlo, pues a veces hay que leer los offset que vendrían bajo una determinada clave en la respuesta. También, hay URLs concretas para pedir lotes de datos y todo eso debe ofrecerlo la API y explicarlo.

Comment: Por ejemplo, [la API de Twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/pagination) manda un valor bajo `next_cursor`, el cual debes usar para seguir obteniendo el siguiente lote de datos. Tendrías que preparar una nueva petición usando el valor que haya en `next_cursor`. Pero cada API tiene su forma y debe venir explicado en la doc.